# Replica identity value on PostgreSQL read-only replica

Tags: postgresql, replication

In PostgreSQL will the replica identity of a table in a read-only replica database be the same as the replica identity in the primary? I.e., if I run the following query on primary and replica databases will I always get the same result (assuming replication is caught up)?

```sql
SELECT CASE relreplident
          WHEN 'd' THEN 'default'
          WHEN 'n' THEN 'nothing'
          WHEN 'f' THEN 'full'
          WHEN 'i' THEN 'index'
       END AS replica_identity
FROM pg_class c
WHERE oid = 'mytable'::regclass;
```

Comment: Are you talking about streaming replication or logical replication?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe this is for streaming replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query will return the same on both servers, because streaming replication keeps them physically identical.

"Replica identity" is a concept from logical replication, which is something quite different.

Comment: Thanks! In our case, we have the primary and replica set up on AWS RDS, and I'm _assuming_ we're using streaming replication between them (based on the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.Replication.ReadReplicas.html#USER_PostgreSQL.Replication.ReadReplicas.Configuration). We also have a CDC service reading a replication slot off of the primary, which is where my interest in the replica identity comes in, as I only have direct query access on the replica and want to be sure I'm getting the right values.

Comment: I see. Does my answer cover everything?

Comment: I think so; thanks!